# angularjs push object undefined is not a function

Tags: angularjs

So, I have a problem with this code and I don`t know why I get that error

```
$scope.veilingen = {};
$http.get('./helpers/get/Veilingen.php').
success(function(data) {
    if(debugMode) console.log(data);
    $scope.veilingenCache = data;
    for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        console.log($scope.veilingen)
        $scope.veilingen.push({
           test: 'hello'
        });
        console.log($scope.veilingen)
    }
});
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function
>       at http://example.com/includes/controllers/veilingCntrl.js:12:30
>       at http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.18/angular.min.js:72:72
>       at I (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.18/angular.min.js:100:144)
>       at I (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.18/angular.min.js:100:144)
>       at http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.18/angular.min.js:101:308
>       at k.$eval (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.18/angular.min.js:112:32)
>       at k.$digest (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.18/angular.min.js:109:121)
>       at k.$apply (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.18/angular.min.js:112:362)
>       at h (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.18/angular.min.js:72:327)
>       at x (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.18/angular.min.js:77:288)

Line 12 is the push() area. I have searched why this happens but I can`t find it. What I want is that the object veilingen gets the first 2 results and after its load the user can change it with:

```
$scope.setLimitVeiling = function(items) {
    for(var i = 0; i < items; i++) {
        $scope.veilingen.push($scope.veilingenCache[i]);
    }
}
```

But yeah, if push is not working...?

Comment: have you declared $scope.veilingen as an array ??

Comment: objects don't have a push() method. Arrays have. It should be `$scope.veilingen = [];`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`$scope.veilingen` is declared as an object instead of array.

```
$scope.veilingen = [];
```